# Why does Chrome's PushManager return a legacy API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm calling this `pushManager.subscribe` function like this:

```
return navigator.serviceWorker.register(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/sw-notifications.js').then(function(registration) {
  let subscribeOptions = {
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicKey)
  };

  return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
})
.then(function(pushSubscription) {
  return pushSubscription;
});
```

This works fine, and it returns an object that looks like this:

```
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/foo:bar","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"key","auth":"key"}}
```

The documentation says to send a POST request to the `endpoint` URL to send a push notification to the user.

Unfortunately, [it doesn't seem to specify](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user) what sort of body to use for this request.

I tried googling around, and found [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) which says this is the legacy API.

Now I'm confused. Why is the `PushManager` on the latest Chrome returning a legacy API? Should I be using something else? Or is this still fine to use?

I'm trying to enable push notifications for my website, and having trouble figuring out exactly how all these puzzle pieces align.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

The FCM legacy API is not deprecated in any way, and can still be used without issue.

If you're starting on a new project, we recommend that you check out the new (versioned) API because it offers more forward compatibility. But it's still totally fine (and in some cases even necessary) to use the legacy API.

---

*Update*: I asked around a bit and got this elaboration from one of the team members:

> There are two ways to use Web push notifications.
>
> 1. Use the way web standards work, wwhere the browser gives you an endpoint -- which seems to be what you are using.
> 2. Use FCM's web SDK that is built on top of the standard web push protocol.  FCM Web SDK makes it simpler for you to send messages across Web and mobile apps (iOS/Android).  See the documentation on [setting up a JavaScript Firebase Cloud Messaging client app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).  And if you use FCM Web SDK, we recommend you use the new (versioned) API because it offers more forward compatibility.  But it's totally fine to use the legacy API (which is not deprecated in any way).
>
> And if you are using the standard web push protocol, you are totally fine using the endpoint returned to you by the browser.  This endpoint is different for different browsers (Firefox and Edge will return different endpoints).  Chrome's push provider is FCM, and in that case you don't have to worry about what endpoint is returned (FCM will treat it correctly and handle your request).

Comment: Hiya. Yeah, I'd like to use the new API but Chrome's PushManager is returning the legacy API. Will it eventually return the new one? I'm not sure how to use the new one if it's giving me the old one.

Comment: We're 4 years later and Chrome's PushManager is still returning the legacy API which is to be discontinued in 6 months (june 24). Have you find a way around it @RyanPeschel ?